# I am unable to build hybris . Getting error in maven repository WroRunTimeException : connect time out

Tags: maven, sap-commerce-cloud

I am setting up a hybris site which has maven jars dependency . I have copied these jars inside C-->User -->.m2 -->repository

When I run hybris ant all build fails due to this error.

[image]

Can you please help me understand what is missing as I am new to maven ?

I have checked the repository folder . It has a 'ro' .Screenshot attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to put jars into that directory. Maven is supposed to download them from a remote repository.